# Why is there a second basis step for k = 2 in this problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, fibonacci-numbers

I'm new to forum-posting, and apologize in advance for poor formatting. I'm a bit confused on a proof involving Strong Induction and Fibonacci numbers, which displays as an image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Mi6Y.png) (apologies again for formatting).

My impression is that because $k = 2$ generates $F_3 \leq 2F_2$, it should be covered by the assumption that  $F_i \leq 2F_{i-1}$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$, where $k \geq 2$. However, we still take the extra step to confirm that $k = 2$ generates a valid inequality. Why?

It seems to me that the only reason for this would be that the definition of Fibonacci numbers **inherently relies on two prior numbers.** However, I encountered other examples of "Strong" induction, albeit from YouTube examples, that failed to establish two base cases, which has left me confused.

Any explanations would be greatly appreciated, and once again, sorry for the formatting.

Comment: I think they are taking the extra step of checking $k=2$ so they can use the last set of inequalities. If you don't assume $k\geq 3$, then $F_{k-2}$ has no meaning (You don't have an $F_0$ defined)

Comment: This makes a lot of sense - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. The claim is

$$\forall\,n\ge2,F_n\le2F_{n-1}.$$

Hence the base case seems to be

$$F_2\le2F_1,$$ which is true, and the inductive step

$$F_k\le2F_{k-1}\implies F_{k+1}\le2F_k.$$

If we limit ourselves to simple induction, about all we can write is
$$F_{k+1}=F_k+F_{k-1}\le3F_{k-1}$$ and this does not establish the claim.

Hence the correct inductive step is

$$F_{k}\le2F_{k-1}\land F_{k+1}\le2F_{k}\implies F_{k+2}=F_{k+1}+F_k\le 2F_{k}+2F_{k-1}=2F_{k+1}.$$

And for the same reason, the base case has to be

$$F_2\le2F_1\land F_3\le 2F_2.$$

Comment: I think you missed a 2 in front of the RHS of the very last equality, but apart from that, I think this makes a lot of sense, thank you! Just to make sure, the reason step 3 does not establish our claim is because we can't apply our assumption onto Fk-1, correct?

Comment: @viviix. Thanks. Yes, you are right.